# Find all matches in a Java Collection

Tags: java, collections

Ok. Here is a problem. This is my collection : `{2,3,4,2,3,5}`. Let's assume that it is a `List` for now. I would like to search this collection for all matches of `'2'`. I would like indexes of the same. I know that there are `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()` methods in `List` and `Arrays.binarySearch()`. However, all of them return one element indicating the position of the searched element. Is there a simple and efficient way to find all matches? Please note that this question is not limited to primitive types.

Comment: P.S: Thank you all for your responses. I think this one does what I want: http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#select(java.util.Collection, org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate)

Comment: If the above link is broken, look for select method in here http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't binarySearch unless the list is sorted.  If it's sorted, then all the matching items are between indexOf and lastIndexOf.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through the collection and check every element manually.

Comment: This, really.  You could go and make a method for it to simplify things, but your best bet for what I (believe) you want will be to create an array, loop through your passed in collection, and add matching results to your created array, then return it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all the matches, the most strait-forward way is to loop through it.

Simplicity is the best strategy.

Or you have some particular reason not looping through it?

Comment: I would think it wouldn't be an optimum approach to the problem. Too many iterations, too much processor time.

Comment: But if you don't sort the collection ahead, binary search wouldn't do much help either. If you use certain data structure, like a binary tree, the same question would have some different solutions. Collection is too general. So you may want to choose the right data structure according to your needs.

Comment: Is there any third party API out there which has this kind of feature? Apache Commons? Google Collections?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know any API for it. However, I think even if you find one, it would probably use loop in their implementation too. So I still recommend you to use loop. If your collection is too big, it takes a long time for a search, then a database engine would be a nice choice, you don't want to store that much data in your memory.

Comment: "Too many iterations, too much processor time." Since there is no order to your elements, you *must* read and check every element, so any approach must iterate through the entire list somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Try Apache  `CollectionUtil`  class method <del>[countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#countMatches)</del>

Answer (score 1):

Why is it that you want to find the indexes? If possible, consider using something other than a list, like a hash table that allows duplicates or a sorted list so that you reduce your search time. Otherwise the only way you can get all instances of that integer is by manually searching using a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use LambdaJ and you'll have a 'closure like' system for writing your case.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Bolts functional programming library](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=57869). You can do filtering with that.